# Is there a way to create a CTE with values in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I often just want to test out a function, or see what a variable might look like. This could be done by creating a temporary table, but I suspect that there is an easier way.

Basically,

```
WITH cte1 AS (
   SELECT 
      VALUES(1,2,3) AS temp_var1
    , VALUES(4,5,6) AS temp_var2
)
SELECT 
    temp_var1
  , temp_var2
  , (temp_var1 + temp_var2) AS temp_var3
FROM cte1
```

This would return

| temp_var1 | temp_var2 | temp_var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

Darn she's fine.

Note I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.15.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 8.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: 8.2 didn't have CTEs. Also, I don't understand your question. Do you have a working query or not?

Comment: Forgive me, the documentation I was using was out of date. It is Postgres 9.2.24. I do not have a working query. That is the output I would like to generate using something similar to that query

Comment: 9.2 is no longer supported either.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
WITH cte1 (temp_var1, temp_var2) AS (
  VALUES
   (1,4),
   (2,5),
   (3,6)
)
SELECT 
    temp_var1
  , temp_var2
  , (temp_var1 + temp_var2) AS temp_var3
FROM cte1
```